# Mechanism of getting messages in WhatsApp or Telegram when click on a group or channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat, telegram, whatsapp

I want to know how to be cached the messages in the Telegram or WhatsApp? and how to retrieve them? I would like to write a web chat application with NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram chats are entirely online. The cached messages load from local storage. Rest downloads as you scroll.
WhatsApp chats are stored locally in a .db file. Thats once you delete them they are gne forever unless you backup.